# In SSMS, is there a way to display logs directly from a .NET assembly?

Tags: c#, ssms, .net-assembly

I have some procedures with assembly, that should be sent new inserted data to websocker server. Unfortunately, lastly something spoil. It looks like there is some problem in C# assembly part that connect with websocket, but unfortunately I don't know how to inspect it, how to display some logs.

Above I post my assembly with places when I want to add some logs. Maybe someone help me.

```
    using System;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Data.SqlTypes;
    using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
    using System.Net.WebSockets;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    
    public partial class StoredProcedures
    {
        [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
        public static void HelloWorld(String value)
        {
    
            Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlMetaData columnInfo
    = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlMetaData("VALUE", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 256);
            SqlDataRecord greetingRecord
                = new SqlDataRecord(new Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlMetaData[] { columnInfo });
    
            greetingRecord.SetString(0, value);
            SqlContext.Pipe.Send(greetingRecord);
            var ws = new WSClient();
            WSClient.runWSClient(value).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }
    }
    
    public class WSClient
    {
        public static async Task runWSClient(String value)
        {
    
    
            using (ClientWebSocket client = new ClientWebSocket())
            {
                Uri servicesUri = new Uri("wss://websocket.kawczynski.eu");
                var cTs = new CancellationTokenSource();
                cTs.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120));
                try
                {
                    await client.ConnectAsync(servicesUri, cTs.Token);

                    // I need to inspect client.State, to check if assembly connects with ws server
    
                    if (client.State == WebSocketState.Open)
                    {
                        string message = value;

                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
                        {
                            ArraySegment<byte> byteToSend = new ArraySegment<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message));
                            await client.SendAsync(byteToSend, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, cTs.Token);
    
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (WebSocketException e)
                {

                    // I need to display e (error)

                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }
            }
     

   }
}
```

Because this code is running when I inserted new data to the table, I think, I need these logs in SSMS, but I'm not sure. I'm quite new with assembly and SSMS.